# Why flask-sqlalchemy don't write the changes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Changes done on object itself don't change database in certain case:
Having below models.py code:

```
class Task(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "task"
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True,
                      'autoload_with': db.engine}

    [...]

    def action(self, action_type):
        if self.task_type == 1:
            if action_type == 1:
                try:
                    user = User.query.filter(User.n_login == self.requestor).first()
                    role_id = self.value
                    new_user_to_role = UserToRole(user.id, role_id)
                    db.session().add(new_user_to_role)
                    db.session().commit() # HERE WE FACE EXCEPTION INTEGRITYERROR IF ROLE IS ALREADY ASSIGNED
                    self.status = 1
                except IntegrityError as ex:
                    # Already assigned role
                    if "UNIQUE constraint" in ex.args[0]:
                        print("Role was already assigned.")
                        db.session().rollback()
                        self.status = 1
                    else:
                        raise IntegrityError(ex.statement, ex.params, ex.orig)

                except Exception as ex:
                    print(ex)
                    self.status = 999
                    db.session().rollback()
                finally:
                    self.update_timestamp = current_timestamp
```

When I'm facing scenario when user try to assign role which were already assigned I get IntegrityError exception and I'm handling it that I'm rolling back changes and then I'm setting self.status = 1 because the task is done even if the role was previously assigned. But the status is visible only on page until refresh.

Sometimes in debug mode I receive following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely) (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 10720 and this is thread id 13540 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

but It happen only when I'm slowly pressing F8 in debug mode, If I press very fast it does not occur.

Any idea why changes are not written?

Comment: Looks like you don't commit your changes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's as debug mode said - sqlalchemy flushes your changes before making new query, as stated [in sqlalchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#flushing):
`All changes to objects maintained by a Session are tracked - before the database is queried again or before the current transaction is committed, it flushes all pending changes to the database. This is known as the Unit of Work pattern.`

You can save your change to database by `db.session().commit()` after setting `self.status`